# String of arrays parsing

Tags: java, parsing

I have a String like this.

`{"type":"broad","Text":"cat"},{"type":"broad","Text":"dog"}`

```
String[] keyString = getParts({"type":"broad","Text":"cat"},{"type":"broad","Text":"dog"});
for(String part : keyString){
    some code here which gives like this 
    String text = "cat";
    String type = "broad";
}
```

Can some one tell me how can i get text and type separately in a string

```
public static String[] getParts(String keyString) {
  if(keyString.isEmpty()) 
   return null;
  String[] parts  = keyString.split(",");
  return parts;
 }
```

Or is there any easy ways to get the respective strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like JSON, so if you have / create a class with fields `type` and `Text`, you can use [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to parse the string and obtain objects of that class. (You can still split the string with `split(",")` and parse each part as separate JSON string)

Comment: One problem though, the array doesn't start nor ends with `[`, `]` respectively.

Comment: you are right it is JSON string. Initially i had JSONstring like this                                                   JSONString = [{"type":"broad","Text":"cat"},{"type":"broad","Text":"dog"}]     After doing the following                                                            JSONArray arrayKey = new JSONArray(JSONString);              arraykey = {"type":"broad","Text":"cat"},{"type":"broad","Text":"dog"}

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "{\"type\":\"broad\",\"Text\":\"cat\"}," +
                       "{\"type\":\"broad\",\"Text\":\"dog\"}";

        System.out.println(input);

        Pattern partPattern = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");
        Pattern typePattern = Pattern.compile("\"type\":\"([^\"]*)\"");
        Pattern textPattern = Pattern.compile("\"Text\":\"([^\"]*)\"");

        Matcher m = partPattern.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            Matcher typeMatcher = typePattern.matcher(m.group(1));
            Matcher textMatcher = textPattern.matcher(m.group(1));

            String type = typeMatcher.find() ? typeMatcher.group(1) : "n/a";
            String text = textMatcher.find() ? textMatcher.group(1) : "n/a";

            System.out.println(type + ", " + text);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output** ([ideone link](http://ideone.com/UaHpY)):

```
{"type":"broad","Text":"cat"},{"type":"broad","Text":"dog"}
broad, cat
broad, dog
```